# What is too high of a pressure for irrigation systems

Tags: valve

I purchased a home four years ago where the owner installed an irrigation system. I noticed the valves were leaking then and replaced four of eight.  I figured they were old, and wear and tear took it's toll.  Now four years later I replaced the same four again for leaking and found out the owner never put in a pressure regulator. The readings at the street is 90psi, do I need an irrigation pressure regulator? The old valves were 3/4in RainBirds.  They were replaced with 3/4in Orbits.

Comment: 90psi sounds too high ... the rating should be printed on the box  .... or check the orbit website

Comment: Many sprinklers have a max pressure of 60psi. The drip systems are usually 25psi or less.

Comment: @EdBeal -- My Netafim TechLine CV drip system's tubing has a maximum rated pressure of 58 psi.  During actual operation, its typical pressures are 15 - 25 psi.  According to page 35 of Netafim's [Drip Irrigation Handbook:  Understanding the Basics](https://www.netafim.com/499749/globalassets/products/drippers-and-dripperlines/drip-irrigation-system-handbook.pdf), various drip lines have various max operating pressures.  Some are as low as 11 psi; others as high as 58 psi.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  Sounds like your irritation is fed from the main spigot that is before the house pressure reducer valve, in which case 90psi is normal but may be too much for some irrigation systems.  Depends on how the system was designed and how the pressure is diversified.  You could easily put on a pressure reducer and see if that helps while still maintaining good overall pressure.

Comment: there is NO pressure reducer according to the OP. The leaky valves are the control valves not spigot. Are you referring to your system because nothing matches what the question is asking.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I missed some of the details in the OP and jumped to the wrong conclusions.